# how to override css for universal selector

Tags: javascript, html, css, less, saas

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <style>
    a * {
      fill: orange
    }
    
    .svg-try a * {
      fill: green
    }
  </style>
  <div class="svg-try">
    need green color to remove<br/>
    <a href="www.google.com">
      <svg width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M110.444 0.00013H9.56142C9.19369 0.00013 8.83037 0.00013 8.46362 0.00212999C8.15661 0.00412999 7.85205 0.00993997 7.54209 0.01483C6.86872 0.0227317 6.19693 0.081806 5.53257 0.191539C4.86914 0.303662 4.22649 0.515044 3.62636 0.818537C3.02696 1.1246 2.47928 1.52229 2.00317 1.99719C1.52457 2.47076 1.12561 3.01814 0.821647 3.61828C0.516845 4.21723 0.305495 4.85905 0.194895 5.52159C0.0832437 6.1833 0.0231632 6.85263 0.0151925 7.52359C0.00588646 7.83018 0.00490371 8.1378 0 8.44444V31.5586C0.00490371 31.8691 0.00588646 32.1699 0.0151925 32.4805C0.0231656 33.1514 0.0832462 33.8207 0.194895 34.4824C0.305189 35.1453 0.516553 35.7875 0.821647 36.3867C1.12547 36.9849 1.52448 37.5301 2.00317 38.001C2.47747 38.478 3.02551 38.876 3.62636 39.1797C4.22649 39.484 4.86907 39.6967 5.53257 39.8105C6.19705 39.9194 6.86876 39.9785 7.54209 39.9873C7.85205 39.9941 8.15661 39.998 8.46362 39.998C8.83036 40 9.19371 40 9.56142 40H110.444C110.804 40 111.17 40 111.531 39.998C111.836 39.998 112.15 39.9941 112.455 39.9873C113.127 39.9789 113.798 39.9198 114.461 39.8105C115.126 39.6958 115.771 39.4833 116.374 39.1797C116.975 38.8758 117.522 38.4779 117.996 38.001C118.473 37.5282 118.873 36.9835 119.181 36.3867C119.484 35.7871 119.693 35.145 119.802 34.4824C119.914 33.8207 119.976 33.1515 119.988 32.4805C119.992 32.1699 119.992 31.8691 119.992 31.5586C120 31.1953 120 30.834 120 30.4648V9.53623C120 9.17002 120 8.80674 119.992 8.44444C119.992 8.1378 119.992 7.83018 119.988 7.52355C119.976 6.85253 119.914 6.18335 119.802 5.52155C119.693 4.8594 119.483 4.21762 119.181 3.61824C118.562 2.41532 117.58 1.43615 116.374 0.818447C115.771 0.515696 115.126 0.304369 114.461 0.191449C113.798 0.0812325 113.127 0.0221377 112.455 0.01469C112.15 0.00980997 111.836 0.00394999 111.531 0.00199999C111.17 0 110.804 0 110.444 0V0.00013Z" fill="#A6A6A6"></path> <path d="M8.46805 39.1249C8.16252 39.1249 7.86436 39.121 7.56123 39.1142C6.93325 39.106 6.30675 39.0515 5.68685 38.9511C5.10882 38.8518 4.54887 38.6671 4.02546 38.4032C3.50685 38.1414 3.03384 37.7982 2.62454 37.3866C2.20932 36.9799 1.86363 36.5081 1.60117 35.9901C1.33582 35.4687 1.15218 34.9098 1.05665 34.3329C0.953484 33.713 0.897668 33.0862 0.889681 32.4579C0.883323 32.247 0.875 31.5448 0.875 31.5448V8.44432C0.875 8.44432 0.883865 7.75291 0.889731 7.54978C0.897378 6.92246 0.95287 6.29664 1.05573 5.67771C1.15143 5.09924 1.33521 4.53874 1.60071 4.01562C1.86221 3.49794 2.20598 3.02585 2.6187 2.61767C3.03095 2.20562 3.50548 1.8606 4.02497 1.59521C4.54717 1.33209 5.10607 1.14873 5.68292 1.05127C6.30486 0.949836 6.93354 0.894996 7.56369 0.88721L8.46854 0.875H111.525L112.441 0.8877C113.065 0.895099 113.688 0.94945 114.305 1.05029C114.887 1.14897 115.452 1.33361 115.98 1.59814C117.021 2.13298 117.868 2.97916 118.402 4.01806C118.663 4.53757 118.844 5.09349 118.939 5.66697C119.043 6.29097 119.101 6.92172 119.113 7.55418C119.116 7.83738 119.116 8.14158 119.116 8.44432C119.124 8.81931 119.124 9.17624 119.124 9.5361V30.4647C119.124 30.828 119.124 31.1825 119.116 31.5399C119.116 31.8651 119.116 32.163 119.112 32.4696C119.1 33.0908 119.043 33.7103 118.941 34.3231C118.847 34.9042 118.664 35.4674 118.399 35.9931C118.135 36.5055 117.791 36.9731 117.381 37.3788C116.971 37.7926 116.497 38.1378 115.977 38.4013C115.451 38.6673 114.887 38.8526 114.305 38.9511C113.685 39.052 113.058 39.1066 112.43 39.1142C112.136 39.121 111.829 39.1249 111.53 39.1249L110.443 39.1269L8.46805 39.1249Z" fill="black"></path> <path d="M24.8388 20.3013C24.8496 19.4666 25.0719 18.6483 25.4851 17.9223C25.8983 17.1963 26.4889 16.5864 27.202 16.1492C26.749 15.5041 26.1514 14.9731 25.4566 14.5986C24.7618 14.224 23.989 14.0162 23.1996 13.9916C21.5157 13.8153 19.8832 14.9964 19.025 14.9964C18.1503 14.9964 16.8291 14.0091 15.4064 14.0383C14.4862 14.0679 13.5893 14.3348 12.8033 14.8128C12.0172 15.2909 11.3687 15.9638 10.921 16.7661C8.98154 20.1145 10.4282 25.0356 12.286 27.7422C13.2155 29.0675 14.3018 30.548 15.7232 30.4955C17.1142 30.4379 17.6337 29.611 19.3127 29.611C20.9761 29.611 21.4635 30.4955 22.9137 30.4621C24.4063 30.4379 25.3467 29.1308 26.2436 27.7929C26.9114 26.8486 27.4253 25.8049 27.7662 24.7004C26.8991 24.3347 26.1591 23.7225 25.6385 22.9402C25.118 22.158 24.8398 21.2402 24.8388 20.3013V20.3013Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M22.0994 12.2113C22.9132 11.2371 23.3141 9.98493 23.2171 8.7207C21.9737 8.85092 20.8253 9.44348 20.0005 10.3803C19.5972 10.838 19.2884 11.3704 19.0916 11.9472C18.8948 12.5239 18.8139 13.1337 18.8536 13.7417C19.4754 13.7481 20.0907 13.6137 20.6529 13.3486C21.2151 13.0835 21.7097 12.6946 22.0994 12.2113Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M42.4205 27.1396H37.6738L36.5339 30.4961H34.5234L39.0194 18.0781H41.1083L45.6042 30.4961H43.5594L42.4205 27.1396ZM38.1655 25.5908H41.928L40.0732 20.1436H40.0213L38.1655 25.5908Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M55.314 25.9694C55.314 28.7829 53.8039 30.5905 51.5251 30.5905C50.9478 30.6206 50.3737 30.488 49.8685 30.2079C49.3633 29.9277 48.9474 29.5114 48.6685 29.0065H48.6253V33.4909H46.7617V21.4421H48.5656V22.948H48.5999C48.8917 22.4455 49.3146 22.0313 49.8236 21.7495C50.3327 21.4676 50.9088 21.3287 51.4908 21.3474C53.795 21.3474 55.314 23.1638 55.314 25.9694ZM53.3985 25.9694C53.3985 24.1364 52.4485 22.9314 50.9992 22.9314C49.5753 22.9314 48.6175 24.1618 48.6175 25.9694C48.6175 27.7936 49.5753 29.0153 50.9992 29.0153C52.4485 29.0153 53.3985 27.819 53.3985 25.9694Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M65.3062 25.9694C65.3062 28.7829 63.7961 30.5905 61.5173 30.5905C60.94 30.6206 60.3659 30.488 59.8607 30.2079C59.3555 29.9277 58.9396 29.5114 58.6606 29.0065H58.6175V33.4909H56.7539V21.4421H58.5578V22.9479H58.592C58.8838 22.4455 59.3067 22.0313 59.8158 21.7495C60.3248 21.4676 60.901 21.3287 61.483 21.3474C63.7873 21.3474 65.3062 23.1638 65.3062 25.9694ZM63.3907 25.9694C63.3907 24.1364 62.4407 22.9313 60.9914 22.9313C59.5675 22.9313 58.6097 24.1618 58.6097 25.9694C58.6097 27.7936 59.5675 29.0153 60.9914 29.0153C62.4407 29.0153 63.3907 27.819 63.3907 25.9694H63.3907Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M71.9116 27.0362C72.0497 28.2676 73.2494 29.0761 74.8887 29.0761C76.4595 29.0761 77.5896 28.2676 77.5896 27.1572C77.5896 26.1933 76.908 25.6162 75.2941 25.2207L73.6802 24.833C71.3936 24.2822 70.332 23.2158 70.332 21.4853C70.332 19.3428 72.2044 17.8711 74.8632 17.8711C77.4946 17.8711 79.2985 19.3428 79.3592 21.4853H77.4779C77.3653 20.2461 76.338 19.498 74.8368 19.498C73.3355 19.498 72.3082 20.2549 72.3082 21.3564C72.3082 22.2344 72.9643 22.751 74.5694 23.1464L75.9414 23.4824C78.4964 24.0849 79.558 25.1084 79.558 26.9247C79.558 29.248 77.7022 30.7031 74.7506 30.7031C71.9889 30.7031 70.1244 29.2822 70.0039 27.0361L71.9116 27.0362Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M83.5792 19.2998V21.4424H85.3057V22.9141H83.5792V27.9052C83.5792 28.6806 83.9249 29.042 84.6839 29.042C84.8888 29.0384 85.0935 29.024 85.2969 28.999V30.4618C84.9557 30.5254 84.6089 30.5542 84.2618 30.5478C82.4237 30.5478 81.7068 29.8593 81.7068 28.1035V22.9141H80.3867V21.4424H81.7068V19.2998H83.5792Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M86.3047 25.9697C86.3047 23.1211 87.9871 21.3311 90.6107 21.3311C93.243 21.3311 94.9176 23.121 94.9176 25.9697C94.9176 28.8261 93.2519 30.6084 90.6107 30.6084C87.9704 30.6084 86.3047 28.8261 86.3047 25.9697ZM93.0188 25.9697C93.0188 24.0156 92.1208 22.8623 90.6107 22.8623C89.1006 22.8623 88.2035 24.0244 88.2035 25.9697C88.2035 27.9316 89.1006 29.0761 90.6107 29.0761C92.1208 29.0761 93.0187 27.9316 93.0187 25.9697H93.0188Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M96.4551 21.442H98.2325V22.983H98.2756C98.3959 22.5017 98.6786 22.0764 99.0763 21.7785C99.474 21.4806 99.9624 21.3284 100.459 21.3473C100.674 21.3465 100.888 21.3698 101.098 21.4166V23.1549C100.827 23.0723 100.544 23.0343 100.261 23.0426C99.9899 23.0316 99.72 23.0792 99.4695 23.1821C99.2189 23.285 98.9937 23.4407 98.8092 23.6386C98.6247 23.8365 98.4853 24.0719 98.4007 24.3286C98.316 24.5852 98.288 24.8571 98.3187 25.1256V30.4957H96.4551L96.4551 21.442Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M109.69 27.8369C109.439 29.4804 107.834 30.6084 105.781 30.6084C103.139 30.6084 101.5 28.8437 101.5 26.0127C101.5 23.1728 103.148 21.3311 105.702 21.3311C108.214 21.3311 109.794 23.0517 109.794 25.7969V26.4336H103.381V26.5459C103.352 26.8791 103.393 27.2147 103.504 27.5306C103.614 27.8464 103.791 28.1352 104.022 28.3777C104.253 28.6203 104.533 28.8111 104.844 28.9374C105.154 29.0637 105.488 29.1226 105.824 29.1103C106.264 29.1515 106.706 29.0498 107.084 28.8203C107.461 28.5909 107.755 28.246 107.92 27.8369L109.69 27.8369ZM103.39 25.1348H107.929C107.946 24.8352 107.9 24.5353 107.795 24.2541C107.69 23.9729 107.528 23.7164 107.319 23.5006C107.11 23.2849 106.858 23.1145 106.58 23.0003C106.302 22.8861 106.003 22.8305 105.702 22.8369C105.399 22.8351 105.098 22.8932 104.817 23.008C104.536 23.1227 104.281 23.2918 104.066 23.5054C103.851 23.7191 103.681 23.973 103.565 24.2527C103.449 24.5323 103.389 24.8321 103.39 25.1348V25.1348Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M37.9328 8.73138C38.3235 8.70342 38.7156 8.76228 39.0807 8.90371C39.4458 9.04515 39.7749 9.26563 40.0443 9.54925C40.3136 9.83287 40.5165 10.1726 40.6382 10.5438C40.76 10.9151 40.7975 11.3087 40.7483 11.6962C40.7483 13.6025 39.7151 14.6982 37.9328 14.6982H35.7715V8.73138H37.9328ZM36.7008 13.8544H37.829C38.1082 13.871 38.3876 13.8254 38.6468 13.7207C38.9061 13.6161 39.1387 13.4552 39.3277 13.2496C39.5167 13.0441 39.6574 12.799 39.7395 12.5324C39.8216 12.2658 39.843 11.9843 39.8023 11.7084C39.8401 11.4335 39.8165 11.1538 39.7331 10.8891C39.6498 10.6244 39.5087 10.3814 39.3202 10.1775C39.1316 9.97358 38.9001 9.81377 38.6423 9.70954C38.3845 9.6053 38.1067 9.55922 37.829 9.57459H36.7008V13.8544Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M41.7991 12.4448C41.7707 12.1489 41.8047 11.8503 41.8988 11.5682C41.9929 11.2861 42.1451 11.0268 42.3456 10.8068C42.5461 10.5868 42.7905 10.4111 43.0631 10.2908C43.3357 10.1705 43.6305 10.1084 43.9286 10.1084C44.2267 10.1084 44.5215 10.1705 44.7942 10.2908C45.0668 10.4111 45.3112 10.5868 45.5117 10.8068C45.7122 11.0268 45.8644 11.2861 45.9585 11.5682C46.0526 11.8503 46.0865 12.1489 46.0581 12.4448C46.087 12.741 46.0535 13.04 45.9596 13.3225C45.8658 13.605 45.7137 13.8648 45.5131 14.0853C45.3126 14.3057 45.068 14.4818 44.7951 14.6023C44.5222 14.7229 44.2271 14.7851 43.9286 14.7851C43.6302 14.7851 43.335 14.7229 43.0621 14.6023C42.7892 14.4818 42.5447 14.3057 42.3441 14.0853C42.1436 13.8648 41.9915 13.605 41.8976 13.3225C41.8038 13.04 41.7702 12.741 41.7991 12.4448V12.4448ZM45.1415 12.4448C45.1415 11.4687 44.7018 10.8979 43.9301 10.8979C43.1555 10.8979 42.7197 11.4687 42.7197 12.4448C42.7197 13.4287 43.1555 13.9951 43.9301 13.9951C44.7018 13.9951 45.1415 13.4247 45.1415 12.4448H45.1415Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M51.7191 14.6982H50.7947L49.8614 11.3818H49.7909L48.8615 14.6982H47.9459L46.7012 10.1953H47.6051L48.414 13.6313H48.4806L49.4089 10.1953H50.2639L51.1923 13.6313H51.2628L52.0677 10.1953H52.9589L51.7191 14.6982Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M54.0059 10.1958H54.8637V10.9112H54.9303C55.0433 10.6543 55.2338 10.4389 55.4754 10.2951C55.7169 10.1513 55.9974 10.0862 56.2778 10.1089C56.4976 10.0925 56.7182 10.1255 56.9233 10.2056C57.1285 10.2857 57.313 10.4108 57.4631 10.5716C57.6132 10.7325 57.7251 10.9249 57.7905 11.1347C57.8558 11.3446 57.873 11.5664 57.8408 11.7837V14.6987H56.9496V12.0069C56.9496 11.2833 56.6343 10.9234 55.9752 10.9234C55.8261 10.9165 55.6771 10.9418 55.5387 10.9976C55.4003 11.0534 55.2756 11.1385 55.1731 11.2468C55.0707 11.3552 54.993 11.4844 54.9454 11.6255C54.8977 11.7667 54.8812 11.9164 54.897 12.0645V14.6988H54.0059L54.0059 10.1958Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M59.2598 8.4375H60.1509V14.6982H59.2598V8.4375Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M61.3909 12.4449C61.3625 12.1489 61.3965 11.8503 61.4906 11.5683C61.5848 11.2862 61.737 11.0268 61.9375 10.8068C62.138 10.5869 62.3824 10.4111 62.6551 10.2908C62.9277 10.1705 63.2225 10.1084 63.5206 10.1084C63.8188 10.1084 64.1136 10.1705 64.3862 10.2908C64.6589 10.4111 64.9033 10.5869 65.1038 10.8068C65.3043 11.0268 65.4565 11.2862 65.5507 11.5683C65.6448 11.8503 65.6787 12.1489 65.6504 12.4449C65.6793 12.7411 65.6457 13.0401 65.5518 13.3226C65.4579 13.6051 65.3058 13.8649 65.1052 14.0853C64.9047 14.3057 64.6601 14.4819 64.3872 14.6024C64.1143 14.7229 63.8191 14.7852 63.5206 14.7852C63.2222 14.7852 62.927 14.7229 62.6541 14.6024C62.3812 14.4819 62.1366 14.3057 61.936 14.0853C61.7355 13.8649 61.5834 13.6051 61.4895 13.3226C61.3956 13.0401 61.362 12.7411 61.3909 12.4449V12.4449ZM64.7333 12.4449C64.7333 11.4688 64.2935 10.898 63.5219 10.898C62.7472 10.898 62.3115 11.4688 62.3115 12.4449C62.3115 13.4288 62.7473 13.9951 63.5219 13.9951C64.2936 13.9951 64.7333 13.4248 64.7333 12.4449H64.7333Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M66.5879 13.4248C66.5879 12.6142 67.1931 12.147 68.2674 12.0806L69.4905 12.0102V11.6216C69.4905 11.146 69.1752 10.8774 68.5661 10.8774C68.0686 10.8774 67.7239 11.0596 67.625 11.3779H66.7622C66.8533 10.6045 67.5829 10.1084 68.6072 10.1084C69.7393 10.1084 70.3778 10.6704 70.3778 11.6216V14.6982H69.5199V14.0654H69.4494C69.3063 14.2924 69.1053 14.4775 68.867 14.6017C68.6288 14.7259 68.3617 14.7848 68.0931 14.7724C67.9035 14.7921 67.7119 14.7719 67.5307 14.7132C67.3494 14.6545 67.1825 14.5586 67.0406 14.4316C66.8988 14.3047 66.7853 14.1495 66.7073 13.976C66.6293 13.8026 66.5886 13.6148 66.5879 13.4248V13.4248ZM69.4905 13.04V12.6636L68.3878 12.7339C67.766 12.7754 67.4839 12.9863 67.4839 13.3833C67.4839 13.7885 67.8365 14.0244 68.3213 14.0244C68.4633 14.0387 68.6068 14.0244 68.7432 13.9823C68.8796 13.9402 69.0061 13.8712 69.1152 13.7794C69.2243 13.6875 69.3137 13.5748 69.3782 13.4477C69.4427 13.3207 69.4809 13.1821 69.4905 13.04V13.04Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M71.5488 12.4448C71.5488 11.022 72.2823 10.1206 73.4232 10.1206C73.7054 10.1076 73.9855 10.1751 74.2307 10.3149C74.4759 10.4548 74.6761 10.6614 74.8079 10.9106H74.8745V8.4375H75.7657V14.6982H74.9117V13.9868H74.8412C74.6992 14.2343 74.492 14.4383 74.2421 14.5768C73.9921 14.7153 73.709 14.7829 73.4232 14.7724C72.2745 14.7725 71.5488 13.8711 71.5488 12.4448ZM72.4694 12.4448C72.4694 13.3999 72.9209 13.9746 73.6759 13.9746C74.427 13.9746 74.8912 13.3916 74.8912 12.4487C74.8912 11.5103 74.4221 10.919 73.6759 10.919C72.9257 10.919 72.4694 11.4976 72.4694 12.4448H72.4694Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M79.4534 12.4448C79.425 12.1489 79.459 11.8503 79.5531 11.5682C79.6472 11.2861 79.7994 11.0268 79.9999 10.8068C80.2004 10.5868 80.4448 10.4111 80.7174 10.2908C80.99 10.1705 81.2848 10.1084 81.5829 10.1084C81.881 10.1084 82.1758 10.1705 82.4485 10.2908C82.7211 10.4111 82.9655 10.5868 83.166 10.8068C83.3665 11.0268 83.5186 11.2861 83.6127 11.5682C83.7069 11.8503 83.7408 12.1489 83.7124 12.4448C83.7413 12.741 83.7078 13.04 83.6139 13.3225C83.5201 13.605 83.368 13.8648 83.1674 14.0853C82.9669 14.3057 82.7223 14.4818 82.4494 14.6023C82.1765 14.7229 81.8814 14.7851 81.5829 14.7851C81.2845 14.7851 80.9893 14.7229 80.7164 14.6023C80.4435 14.4818 80.199 14.3057 79.9984 14.0853C79.7978 13.8648 79.6458 13.605 79.5519 13.3225C79.458 13.04 79.4245 12.741 79.4534 12.4448V12.4448ZM82.7958 12.4448C82.7958 11.4687 82.3561 10.8979 81.5844 10.8979C80.8098 10.8979 80.374 11.4687 80.374 12.4448C80.374 13.4287 80.8098 13.9951 81.5844 13.9951C82.3561 13.9951 82.7958 13.4247 82.7958 12.4448Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M84.9062 10.1958H85.7641V10.9112H85.8307C85.9437 10.6543 86.1342 10.4389 86.3758 10.2951C86.6173 10.1513 86.8978 10.0862 87.1782 10.1089C87.3979 10.0925 87.6186 10.1255 87.8237 10.2056C88.0289 10.2857 88.2134 10.4108 88.3635 10.5716C88.5136 10.7325 88.6255 10.9249 88.6909 11.1347C88.7562 11.3446 88.7734 11.5664 88.7412 11.7837V14.6987H87.85V12.0069C87.85 11.2833 87.5347 10.9234 86.8756 10.9234C86.7265 10.9165 86.5775 10.9418 86.4391 10.9976C86.3006 11.0534 86.1759 11.1385 86.0735 11.2468C85.9711 11.3552 85.8934 11.4844 85.8458 11.6255C85.7981 11.7667 85.7816 11.9164 85.7974 12.0645V14.6988H84.9062V10.1958Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M93.7789 9.07422V10.2158H94.7572V10.9644H93.7789V13.2798C93.7789 13.7515 93.9738 13.958 94.4174 13.958C94.531 13.9576 94.6444 13.9508 94.7572 13.9375V14.6777C94.5972 14.7063 94.435 14.7214 94.2725 14.7231C93.2814 14.7231 92.8868 14.3755 92.8868 13.5073V10.9643H92.1699V10.2158H92.8868V9.07422H93.7789Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M95.9727 8.4375H96.856V10.9189H96.9265C97.045 10.6596 97.2407 10.443 97.4871 10.2987C97.7335 10.1543 98.0185 10.0893 98.3033 10.1123C98.5219 10.1004 98.7404 10.1368 98.9433 10.2189C99.1461 10.3009 99.3283 10.4266 99.4768 10.5869C99.6254 10.7473 99.7366 10.9383 99.8026 11.1464C99.8685 11.3546 99.8876 11.5747 99.8585 11.791V14.6982H98.9664V12.0102C98.9664 11.291 98.6305 10.9267 98.0008 10.9267C97.8477 10.9142 97.6936 10.9352 97.5494 10.9883C97.4052 11.0413 97.2744 11.1251 97.1661 11.2339C97.0578 11.3426 96.9747 11.4736 96.9225 11.6178C96.8702 11.7619 96.8502 11.9157 96.8639 12.0683V14.6982H95.9727L95.9727 8.4375Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M105.056 13.4825C104.935 13.894 104.673 14.25 104.315 14.4882C103.957 14.7263 103.527 14.8315 103.099 14.7852C102.802 14.793 102.506 14.7362 102.233 14.6187C101.96 14.5012 101.715 14.3257 101.517 14.1046C101.318 13.8835 101.171 13.6219 101.084 13.3381C100.997 13.0543 100.973 12.755 101.013 12.461C100.974 12.1661 100.998 11.8662 101.085 11.5815C101.172 11.2968 101.319 11.0341 101.516 10.811C101.714 10.5879 101.957 10.4098 102.229 10.2886C102.502 10.1674 102.797 10.1059 103.095 10.1085C104.352 10.1085 105.11 10.9645 105.11 12.3785V12.6886H101.921V12.7384C101.907 12.9036 101.928 13.0699 101.982 13.2267C102.037 13.3834 102.123 13.5271 102.236 13.6486C102.35 13.77 102.487 13.8666 102.64 13.932C102.793 13.9974 102.958 14.0302 103.124 14.0284C103.337 14.0539 103.553 14.0156 103.744 13.9184C103.936 13.8212 104.094 13.6694 104.198 13.4825L105.056 13.4825ZM101.921 12.0313H104.202C104.213 11.8802 104.193 11.7284 104.142 11.5857C104.09 11.443 104.01 11.3125 103.905 11.2026C103.801 11.0928 103.674 11.006 103.534 10.9478C103.393 10.8896 103.242 10.8613 103.09 10.8648C102.936 10.8629 102.783 10.8917 102.641 10.9497C102.498 11.0076 102.368 11.0935 102.259 11.2022C102.15 11.3109 102.064 11.4403 102.006 11.5827C101.948 11.7251 101.919 11.8776 101.921 12.0313H101.921Z" fill="white"></path></svg></a>
  </div>

  Original icon<br/>

  <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
    <p>My footer information</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

We need to override the universal selector css need to override, we need universal selector css as well. can help how to remove the color so that svg image as in screen we can display inside a tag.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: here is a solution maintaining your global css.

These 2 are your issues:

```
a * {
      fill: orange
}
    
.svg-try a * {
      fill: green
}
```

Do this:

```
a:not(svg) {
      fill: orange;
    }
    
.svg-try a:not(svg) {
      fill: green;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<body>
  <style>
   a*:not(svg) {
      fill: orange;
    }
    
    .svg-try a*:not(svg) {
      fill: green;
    }
    
  
  </style>
  <div class="svg-try">
    need green color to remove<br/>
    <a href="www.google.com">
      <svg width="120" height="40" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 120 40"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M110.444 0.00013H9.56142C9.19369 0.00013 8.83037 0.00013 8.46362 0.00212999C8.15661 0.00412999 7.85205 0.00993997 7.54209 0.01483C6.86872 0.0227317 6.19693 0.081806 5.53257 0.191539C4.86914 0.303662 4.22649 0.515044 3.62636 0.818537C3.02696 1.1246 2.47928 1.52229 2.00317 1.99719C1.52457 2.47076 1.12561 3.01814 0.821647 3.61828C0.516845 4.21723 0.305495 4.85905 0.194895 5.52159C0.0832437 6.1833 0.0231632 6.85263 0.0151925 7.52359C0.00588646 7.83018 0.00490371 8.1378 0 8.44444V31.5586C0.00490371 31.8691 0.00588646 32.1699 0.0151925 32.4805C0.0231656 33.1514 0.0832462 33.8207 0.194895 34.4824C0.305189 35.1453 0.516553 35.7875 0.821647 36.3867C1.12547 36.9849 1.52448 37.5301 2.00317 38.001C2.47747 38.478 3.02551 38.876 3.62636 39.1797C4.22649 39.484 4.86907 39.6967 5.53257 39.8105C6.19705 39.9194 6.86876 39.9785 7.54209 39.9873C7.85205 39.9941 8.15661 39.998 8.46362 39.998C8.83036 40 9.19371 40 9.56142 40H110.444C110.804 40 111.17 40 111.531 39.998C111.836 39.998 112.15 39.9941 112.455 39.9873C113.127 39.9789 113.798 39.9198 114.461 39.8105C115.126 39.6958 115.771 39.4833 116.374 39.1797C116.975 38.8758 117.522 38.4779 117.996 38.001C118.473 37.5282 118.873 36.9835 119.181 36.3867C119.484 35.7871 119.693 35.145 119.802 34.4824C119.914 33.8207 119.976 33.1515 119.988 32.4805C119.992 32.1699 119.992 31.8691 119.992 31.5586C120 31.1953 120 30.834 120 30.4648V9.53623C120 9.17002 120 8.80674 119.992 8.44444C119.992 8.1378 119.992 7.83018 119.988 7.52355C119.976 6.85253 119.914 6.18335 119.802 5.52155C119.693 4.8594 119.483 4.21762 119.181 3.61824C118.562 2.41532 117.58 1.43615 116.374 0.818447C115.771 0.515696 115.126 0.304369 114.461 0.191449C113.798 0.0812325 113.127 0.0221377 112.455 0.01469C112.15 0.00980997 111.836 0.00394999 111.531 0.00199999C111.17 0 110.804 0 110.444 0V0.00013Z" fill="#A6A6A6"></path> <path d="M8.46805 39.1249C8.16252 39.1249 7.86436 39.121 7.56123 39.1142C6.93325 39.106 6.30675 39.0515 5.68685 38.9511C5.10882 38.8518 4.54887 38.6671 4.02546 38.4032C3.50685 38.1414 3.03384 37.7982 2.62454 37.3866C2.20932 36.9799 1.86363 36.5081 1.60117 35.9901C1.33582 35.4687 1.15218 34.9098 1.05665 34.3329C0.953484 33.713 0.897668 33.0862 0.889681 32.4579C0.883323 32.247 0.875 31.5448 0.875 31.5448V8.44432C0.875 8.44432 0.883865 7.75291 0.889731 7.54978C0.897378 6.92246 0.95287 6.29664 1.05573 5.67771C1.15143 5.09924 1.33521 4.53874 1.60071 4.01562C1.86221 3.49794 2.20598 3.02585 2.6187 2.61767C3.03095 2.20562 3.50548 1.8606 4.02497 1.59521C4.54717 1.33209 5.10607 1.14873 5.68292 1.05127C6.30486 0.949836 6.93354 0.894996 7.56369 0.88721L8.46854 0.875H111.525L112.441 0.8877C113.065 0.895099 113.688 0.94945 114.305 1.05029C114.887 1.14897 115.452 1.33361 115.98 1.59814C117.021 2.13298 117.868 2.97916 118.402 4.01806C118.663 4.53757 118.844 5.09349 118.939 5.66697C119.043 6.29097 119.101 6.92172 119.113 7.55418C119.116 7.83738 119.116 8.14158 119.116 8.44432C119.124 8.81931 119.124 9.17624 119.124 9.5361V30.4647C119.124 30.828 119.124 31.1825 119.116 31.5399C119.116 31.8651 119.116 32.163 119.112 32.4696C119.1 33.0908 119.043 33.7103 118.941 34.3231C118.847 34.9042 118.664 35.4674 118.399 35.9931C118.135 36.5055 117.791 36.9731 117.381 37.3788C116.971 37.7926 116.497 38.1378 115.977 38.4013C115.451 38.6673 114.887 38.8526 114.305 38.9511C113.685 39.052 113.058 39.1066 112.43 39.1142C112.136 39.121 111.829 39.1249 111.53 39.1249L110.443 39.1269L8.46805 39.1249Z" fill="black"></path> <path d="M24.8388 20.3013C24.8496 19.4666 25.0719 18.6483 25.4851 17.9223C25.8983 17.1963 26.4889 16.5864 27.202 16.1492C26.749 15.5041 26.1514 14.9731 25.4566 14.5986C24.7618 14.224 23.989 14.0162 23.1996 13.9916C21.5157 13.8153 19.8832 14.9964 19.025 14.9964C18.1503 14.9964 16.8291 14.0091 15.4064 14.0383C14.4862 14.0679 13.5893 14.3348 12.8033 14.8128C12.0172 15.2909 11.3687 15.9638 10.921 16.7661C8.98154 20.1145 10.4282 25.0356 12.286 27.7422C13.2155 29.0675 14.3018 30.548 15.7232 30.4955C17.1142 30.4379 17.6337 29.611 19.3127 29.611C20.9761 29.611 21.4635 30.4955 22.9137 30.4621C24.4063 30.4379 25.3467 29.1308 26.2436 27.7929C26.9114 26.8486 27.4253 25.8049 27.7662 24.7004C26.8991 24.3347 26.1591 23.7225 25.6385 22.9402C25.118 22.158 24.8398 21.2402 24.8388 20.3013V20.3013Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M22.0994 12.2113C22.9132 11.2371 23.3141 9.98493 23.2171 8.7207C21.9737 8.85092 20.8253 9.44348 20.0005 10.3803C19.5972 10.838 19.2884 11.3704 19.0916 11.9472C18.8948 12.5239 18.8139 13.1337 18.8536 13.7417C19.4754 13.7481 20.0907 13.6137 20.6529 13.3486C21.2151 13.0835 21.7097 12.6946 22.0994 12.2113Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M42.4205 27.1396H37.6738L36.5339 30.4961H34.5234L39.0194 18.0781H41.1083L45.6042 30.4961H43.5594L42.4205 27.1396ZM38.1655 25.5908H41.928L40.0732 20.1436H40.0213L38.1655 25.5908Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M55.314 25.9694C55.314 28.7829 53.8039 30.5905 51.5251 30.5905C50.9478 30.6206 50.3737 30.488 49.8685 30.2079C49.3633 29.9277 48.9474 29.5114 48.6685 29.0065H48.6253V33.4909H46.7617V21.4421H48.5656V22.948H48.5999C48.8917 22.4455 49.3146 22.0313 49.8236 21.7495C50.3327 21.4676 50.9088 21.3287 51.4908 21.3474C53.795 21.3474 55.314 23.1638 55.314 25.9694ZM53.3985 25.9694C53.3985 24.1364 52.4485 22.9314 50.9992 22.9314C49.5753 22.9314 48.6175 24.1618 48.6175 25.9694C48.6175 27.7936 49.5753 29.0153 50.9992 29.0153C52.4485 29.0153 53.3985 27.819 53.3985 25.9694Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M65.3062 25.9694C65.3062 28.7829 63.7961 30.5905 61.5173 30.5905C60.94 30.6206 60.3659 30.488 59.8607 30.2079C59.3555 29.9277 58.9396 29.5114 58.6606 29.0065H58.6175V33.4909H56.7539V21.4421H58.5578V22.9479H58.592C58.8838 22.4455 59.3067 22.0313 59.8158 21.7495C60.3248 21.4676 60.901 21.3287 61.483 21.3474C63.7873 21.3474 65.3062 23.1638 65.3062 25.9694ZM63.3907 25.9694C63.3907 24.1364 62.4407 22.9313 60.9914 22.9313C59.5675 22.9313 58.6097 24.1618 58.6097 25.9694C58.6097 27.7936 59.5675 29.0153 60.9914 29.0153C62.4407 29.0153 63.3907 27.819 63.3907 25.9694H63.3907Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M71.9116 27.0362C72.0497 28.2676 73.2494 29.0761 74.8887 29.0761C76.4595 29.0761 77.5896 28.2676 77.5896 27.1572C77.5896 26.1933 76.908 25.6162 75.2941 25.2207L73.6802 24.833C71.3936 24.2822 70.332 23.2158 70.332 21.4853C70.332 19.3428 72.2044 17.8711 74.8632 17.8711C77.4946 17.8711 79.2985 19.3428 79.3592 21.4853H77.4779C77.3653 20.2461 76.338 19.498 74.8368 19.498C73.3355 19.498 72.3082 20.2549 72.3082 21.3564C72.3082 22.2344 72.9643 22.751 74.5694 23.1464L75.9414 23.4824C78.4964 24.0849 79.558 25.1084 79.558 26.9247C79.558 29.248 77.7022 30.7031 74.7506 30.7031C71.9889 30.7031 70.1244 29.2822 70.0039 27.0361L71.9116 27.0362Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M83.5792 19.2998V21.4424H85.3057V22.9141H83.5792V27.9052C83.5792 28.6806 83.9249 29.042 84.6839 29.042C84.8888 29.0384 85.0935 29.024 85.2969 28.999V30.4618C84.9557 30.5254 84.6089 30.5542 84.2618 30.5478C82.4237 30.5478 81.7068 29.8593 81.7068 28.1035V22.9141H80.3867V21.4424H81.7068V19.2998H83.5792Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M86.3047 25.9697C86.3047 23.1211 87.9871 21.3311 90.6107 21.3311C93.243 21.3311 94.9176 23.121 94.9176 25.9697C94.9176 28.8261 93.2519 30.6084 90.6107 30.6084C87.9704 30.6084 86.3047 28.8261 86.3047 25.9697ZM93.0188 25.9697C93.0188 24.0156 92.1208 22.8623 90.6107 22.8623C89.1006 22.8623 88.2035 24.0244 88.2035 25.9697C88.2035 27.9316 89.1006 29.0761 90.6107 29.0761C92.1208 29.0761 93.0187 27.9316 93.0187 25.9697H93.0188Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M96.4551 21.442H98.2325V22.983H98.2756C98.3959 22.5017 98.6786 22.0764 99.0763 21.7785C99.474 21.4806 99.9624 21.3284 100.459 21.3473C100.674 21.3465 100.888 21.3698 101.098 21.4166V23.1549C100.827 23.0723 100.544 23.0343 100.261 23.0426C99.9899 23.0316 99.72 23.0792 99.4695 23.1821C99.2189 23.285 98.9937 23.4407 98.8092 23.6386C98.6247 23.8365 98.4853 24.0719 98.4007 24.3286C98.316 24.5852 98.288 24.8571 98.3187 25.1256V30.4957H96.4551L96.4551 21.442Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M109.69 27.8369C109.439 29.4804 107.834 30.6084 105.781 30.6084C103.139 30.6084 101.5 28.8437 101.5 26.0127C101.5 23.1728 103.148 21.3311 105.702 21.3311C108.214 21.3311 109.794 23.0517 109.794 25.7969V26.4336H103.381V26.5459C103.352 26.8791 103.393 27.2147 103.504 27.5306C103.614 27.8464 103.791 28.1352 104.022 28.3777C104.253 28.6203 104.533 28.8111 104.844 28.9374C105.154 29.0637 105.488 29.1226 105.824 29.1103C106.264 29.1515 106.706 29.0498 107.084 28.8203C107.461 28.5909 107.755 28.246 107.92 27.8369L109.69 27.8369ZM103.39 25.1348H107.929C107.946 24.8352 107.9 24.5353 107.795 24.2541C107.69 23.9729 107.528 23.7164 107.319 23.5006C107.11 23.2849 106.858 23.1145 106.58 23.0003C106.302 22.8861 106.003 22.8305 105.702 22.8369C105.399 22.8351 105.098 22.8932 104.817 23.008C104.536 23.1227 104.281 23.2918 104.066 23.5054C103.851 23.7191 103.681 23.973 103.565 24.2527C103.449 24.5323 103.389 24.8321 103.39 25.1348V25.1348Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M37.9328 8.73138C38.3235 8.70342 38.7156 8.76228 39.0807 8.90371C39.4458 9.04515 39.7749 9.26563 40.0443 9.54925C40.3136 9.83287 40.5165 10.1726 40.6382 10.5438C40.76 10.9151 40.7975 11.3087 40.7483 11.6962C40.7483 13.6025 39.7151 14.6982 37.9328 14.6982H35.7715V8.73138H37.9328ZM36.7008 13.8544H37.829C38.1082 13.871 38.3876 13.8254 38.6468 13.7207C38.9061 13.6161 39.1387 13.4552 39.3277 13.2496C39.5167 13.0441 39.6574 12.799 39.7395 12.5324C39.8216 12.2658 39.843 11.9843 39.8023 11.7084C39.8401 11.4335 39.8165 11.1538 39.7331 10.8891C39.6498 10.6244 39.5087 10.3814 39.3202 10.1775C39.1316 9.97358 38.9001 9.81377 38.6423 9.70954C38.3845 9.6053 38.1067 9.55922 37.829 9.57459H36.7008V13.8544Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M41.7991 12.4448C41.7707 12.1489 41.8047 11.8503 41.8988 11.5682C41.9929 11.2861 42.1451 11.0268 42.3456 10.8068C42.5461 10.5868 42.7905 10.4111 43.0631 10.2908C43.3357 10.1705 43.6305 10.1084 43.9286 10.1084C44.2267 10.1084 44.5215 10.1705 44.7942 10.2908C45.0668 10.4111 45.3112 10.5868 45.5117 10.8068C45.7122 11.0268 45.8644 11.2861 45.9585 11.5682C46.0526 11.8503 46.0865 12.1489 46.0581 12.4448C46.087 12.741 46.0535 13.04 45.9596 13.3225C45.8658 13.605 45.7137 13.8648 45.5131 14.0853C45.3126 14.3057 45.068 14.4818 44.7951 14.6023C44.5222 14.7229 44.2271 14.7851 43.9286 14.7851C43.6302 14.7851 43.335 14.7229 43.0621 14.6023C42.7892 14.4818 42.5447 14.3057 42.3441 14.0853C42.1436 13.8648 41.9915 13.605 41.8976 13.3225C41.8038 13.04 41.7702 12.741 41.7991 12.4448V12.4448ZM45.1415 12.4448C45.1415 11.4687 44.7018 10.8979 43.9301 10.8979C43.1555 10.8979 42.7197 11.4687 42.7197 12.4448C42.7197 13.4287 43.1555 13.9951 43.9301 13.9951C44.7018 13.9951 45.1415 13.4247 45.1415 12.4448H45.1415Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M51.7191 14.6982H50.7947L49.8614 11.3818H49.7909L48.8615 14.6982H47.9459L46.7012 10.1953H47.6051L48.414 13.6313H48.4806L49.4089 10.1953H50.2639L51.1923 13.6313H51.2628L52.0677 10.1953H52.9589L51.7191 14.6982Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M54.0059 10.1958H54.8637V10.9112H54.9303C55.0433 10.6543 55.2338 10.4389 55.4754 10.2951C55.7169 10.1513 55.9974 10.0862 56.2778 10.1089C56.4976 10.0925 56.7182 10.1255 56.9233 10.2056C57.1285 10.2857 57.313 10.4108 57.4631 10.5716C57.6132 10.7325 57.7251 10.9249 57.7905 11.1347C57.8558 11.3446 57.873 11.5664 57.8408 11.7837V14.6987H56.9496V12.0069C56.9496 11.2833 56.6343 10.9234 55.9752 10.9234C55.8261 10.9165 55.6771 10.9418 55.5387 10.9976C55.4003 11.0534 55.2756 11.1385 55.1731 11.2468C55.0707 11.3552 54.993 11.4844 54.9454 11.6255C54.8977 11.7667 54.8812 11.9164 54.897 12.0645V14.6988H54.0059L54.0059 10.1958Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M59.2598 8.4375H60.1509V14.6982H59.2598V8.4375Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M61.3909 12.4449C61.3625 12.1489 61.3965 11.8503 61.4906 11.5683C61.5848 11.2862 61.737 11.0268 61.9375 10.8068C62.138 10.5869 62.3824 10.4111 62.6551 10.2908C62.9277 10.1705 63.2225 10.1084 63.5206 10.1084C63.8188 10.1084 64.1136 10.1705 64.3862 10.2908C64.6589 10.4111 64.9033 10.5869 65.1038 10.8068C65.3043 11.0268 65.4565 11.2862 65.5507 11.5683C65.6448 11.8503 65.6787 12.1489 65.6504 12.4449C65.6793 12.7411 65.6457 13.0401 65.5518 13.3226C65.4579 13.6051 65.3058 13.8649 65.1052 14.0853C64.9047 14.3057 64.6601 14.4819 64.3872 14.6024C64.1143 14.7229 63.8191 14.7852 63.5206 14.7852C63.2222 14.7852 62.927 14.7229 62.6541 14.6024C62.3812 14.4819 62.1366 14.3057 61.936 14.0853C61.7355 13.8649 61.5834 13.6051 61.4895 13.3226C61.3956 13.0401 61.362 12.7411 61.3909 12.4449V12.4449ZM64.7333 12.4449C64.7333 11.4688 64.2935 10.898 63.5219 10.898C62.7472 10.898 62.3115 11.4688 62.3115 12.4449C62.3115 13.4288 62.7473 13.9951 63.5219 13.9951C64.2936 13.9951 64.7333 13.4248 64.7333 12.4449H64.7333Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M66.5879 13.4248C66.5879 12.6142 67.1931 12.147 68.2674 12.0806L69.4905 12.0102V11.6216C69.4905 11.146 69.1752 10.8774 68.5661 10.8774C68.0686 10.8774 67.7239 11.0596 67.625 11.3779H66.7622C66.8533 10.6045 67.5829 10.1084 68.6072 10.1084C69.7393 10.1084 70.3778 10.6704 70.3778 11.6216V14.6982H69.5199V14.0654H69.4494C69.3063 14.2924 69.1053 14.4775 68.867 14.6017C68.6288 14.7259 68.3617 14.7848 68.0931 14.7724C67.9035 14.7921 67.7119 14.7719 67.5307 14.7132C67.3494 14.6545 67.1825 14.5586 67.0406 14.4316C66.8988 14.3047 66.7853 14.1495 66.7073 13.976C66.6293 13.8026 66.5886 13.6148 66.5879 13.4248V13.4248ZM69.4905 13.04V12.6636L68.3878 12.7339C67.766 12.7754 67.4839 12.9863 67.4839 13.3833C67.4839 13.7885 67.8365 14.0244 68.3213 14.0244C68.4633 14.0387 68.6068 14.0244 68.7432 13.9823C68.8796 13.9402 69.0061 13.8712 69.1152 13.7794C69.2243 13.6875 69.3137 13.5748 69.3782 13.4477C69.4427 13.3207 69.4809 13.1821 69.4905 13.04V13.04Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M71.5488 12.4448C71.5488 11.022 72.2823 10.1206 73.4232 10.1206C73.7054 10.1076 73.9855 10.1751 74.2307 10.3149C74.4759 10.4548 74.6761 10.6614 74.8079 10.9106H74.8745V8.4375H75.7657V14.6982H74.9117V13.9868H74.8412C74.6992 14.2343 74.492 14.4383 74.2421 14.5768C73.9921 14.7153 73.709 14.7829 73.4232 14.7724C72.2745 14.7725 71.5488 13.8711 71.5488 12.4448ZM72.4694 12.4448C72.4694 13.3999 72.9209 13.9746 73.6759 13.9746C74.427 13.9746 74.8912 13.3916 74.8912 12.4487C74.8912 11.5103 74.4221 10.919 73.6759 10.919C72.9257 10.919 72.4694 11.4976 72.4694 12.4448H72.4694Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M79.4534 12.4448C79.425 12.1489 79.459 11.8503 79.5531 11.5682C79.6472 11.2861 79.7994 11.0268 79.9999 10.8068C80.2004 10.5868 80.4448 10.4111 80.7174 10.2908C80.99 10.1705 81.2848 10.1084 81.5829 10.1084C81.881 10.1084 82.1758 10.1705 82.4485 10.2908C82.7211 10.4111 82.9655 10.5868 83.166 10.8068C83.3665 11.0268 83.5186 11.2861 83.6127 11.5682C83.7069 11.8503 83.7408 12.1489 83.7124 12.4448C83.7413 12.741 83.7078 13.04 83.6139 13.3225C83.5201 13.605 83.368 13.8648 83.1674 14.0853C82.9669 14.3057 82.7223 14.4818 82.4494 14.6023C82.1765 14.7229 81.8814 14.7851 81.5829 14.7851C81.2845 14.7851 80.9893 14.7229 80.7164 14.6023C80.4435 14.4818 80.199 14.3057 79.9984 14.0853C79.7978 13.8648 79.6458 13.605 79.5519 13.3225C79.458 13.04 79.4245 12.741 79.4534 12.4448V12.4448ZM82.7958 12.4448C82.7958 11.4687 82.3561 10.8979 81.5844 10.8979C80.8098 10.8979 80.374 11.4687 80.374 12.4448C80.374 13.4287 80.8098 13.9951 81.5844 13.9951C82.3561 13.9951 82.7958 13.4247 82.7958 12.4448Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M84.9062 10.1958H85.7641V10.9112H85.8307C85.9437 10.6543 86.1342 10.4389 86.3758 10.2951C86.6173 10.1513 86.8978 10.0862 87.1782 10.1089C87.3979 10.0925 87.6186 10.1255 87.8237 10.2056C88.0289 10.2857 88.2134 10.4108 88.3635 10.5716C88.5136 10.7325 88.6255 10.9249 88.6909 11.1347C88.7562 11.3446 88.7734 11.5664 88.7412 11.7837V14.6987H87.85V12.0069C87.85 11.2833 87.5347 10.9234 86.8756 10.9234C86.7265 10.9165 86.5775 10.9418 86.4391 10.9976C86.3006 11.0534 86.1759 11.1385 86.0735 11.2468C85.9711 11.3552 85.8934 11.4844 85.8458 11.6255C85.7981 11.7667 85.7816 11.9164 85.7974 12.0645V14.6988H84.9062V10.1958Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M93.7789 9.07422V10.2158H94.7572V10.9644H93.7789V13.2798C93.7789 13.7515 93.9738 13.958 94.4174 13.958C94.531 13.9576 94.6444 13.9508 94.7572 13.9375V14.6777C94.5972 14.7063 94.435 14.7214 94.2725 14.7231C93.2814 14.7231 92.8868 14.3755 92.8868 13.5073V10.9643H92.1699V10.2158H92.8868V9.07422H93.7789Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M95.9727 8.4375H96.856V10.9189H96.9265C97.045 10.6596 97.2407 10.443 97.4871 10.2987C97.7335 10.1543 98.0185 10.0893 98.3033 10.1123C98.5219 10.1004 98.7404 10.1368 98.9433 10.2189C99.1461 10.3009 99.3283 10.4266 99.4768 10.5869C99.6254 10.7473 99.7366 10.9383 99.8026 11.1464C99.8685 11.3546 99.8876 11.5747 99.8585 11.791V14.6982H98.9664V12.0102C98.9664 11.291 98.6305 10.9267 98.0008 10.9267C97.8477 10.9142 97.6936 10.9352 97.5494 10.9883C97.4052 11.0413 97.2744 11.1251 97.1661 11.2339C97.0578 11.3426 96.9747 11.4736 96.9225 11.6178C96.8702 11.7619 96.8502 11.9157 96.8639 12.0683V14.6982H95.9727L95.9727 8.4375Z" fill="white"></path> <path d="M105.056 13.4825C104.935 13.894 104.673 14.25 104.315 14.4882C103.957 14.7263 103.527 14.8315 103.099 14.7852C102.802 14.793 102.506 14.7362 102.233 14.6187C101.96 14.5012 101.715 14.3257 101.517 14.1046C101.318 13.8835 101.171 13.6219 101.084 13.3381C100.997 13.0543 100.973 12.755 101.013 12.461C100.974 12.1661 100.998 11.8662 101.085 11.5815C101.172 11.2968 101.319 11.0341 101.516 10.811C101.714 10.5879 101.957 10.4098 102.229 10.2886C102.502 10.1674 102.797 10.1059 103.095 10.1085C104.352 10.1085 105.11 10.9645 105.11 12.3785V12.6886H101.921V12.7384C101.907 12.9036 101.928 13.0699 101.982 13.2267C102.037 13.3834 102.123 13.5271 102.236 13.6486C102.35 13.77 102.487 13.8666 102.64 13.932C102.793 13.9974 102.958 14.0302 103.124 14.0284C103.337 14.0539 103.553 14.0156 103.744 13.9184C103.936 13.8212 104.094 13.6694 104.198 13.4825L105.056 13.4825ZM101.921 12.0313H104.202C104.213 11.8802 104.193 11.7284 104.142 11.5857C104.09 11.443 104.01 11.3125 103.905 11.2026C103.801 11.0928 103.674 11.006 103.534 10.9478C103.393 10.8896 103.242 10.8613 103.09 10.8648C102.936 10.8629 102.783 10.8917 102.641 10.9497C102.498 11.0076 102.368 11.0935 102.259 11.2022C102.15 11.3109 102.064 11.4403 102.006 11.5827C101.948 11.7251 101.919 11.8776 101.921 12.0313H101.921Z" fill="white"></path></svg></a>
  </div>

  Original icon<br/>

  <div class="w3-container w3-teal">
    <p>My footer information</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @J_k , but i need ('a , svg') styles like those coming from global, also i don't want to remove SVG attribute **fill="none"**.

Comment: @Mr_vasu Check the solution now. I changed it so it maintains your global css

Answer (score 0):

You could add the desired styles by adding !important before the semi colon to override the external style sheet. You might also want to add the semi colon at the end of your css style statements

Eg:- `fill :red !Important;`

You might also want to remove the fill='none'  attribute in the svg tag.